# Loops/Functions and State abbreviations

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I'm having some issues with some code that my professor has assigned. I've read the textbook a few times, looked at different resources, and still haven't had much luck. Here is what my professor requires.

- create a list named states1 that holds the two-letter abbreviations of the first 10 USA states, in alphabetical order.
- use a loop to process the list and display the abbreviations all on the same line, separated by a single space. See sample output.
- make a second list named states2 by slicing. This new list must hold the middle four state abbreviations from states1.
- execute a function named list_func with states2 as its sole argument.
- inside the list_func function: delete the second element in the list insert the abbreviation for Texas into the list at index 2 prompt the user for the abbreviation of another state of your choice, then append it to the list reverse the list return the list to main
- back in main, use a loop to iterate over the returned list, printing all abbreviations on one line separated by a space.

And here is my code:

```
    def main():
    states1 = ['AL', 'AK', 'AR', 'AZ', 'CA', 'CO', 'CT', 'DE', 'FL', 'GA']
    for words in states1:
        print(words,\
              end = " ")
    states2 = states1[3:7]
    list_func(states2)

def list_func(states2):
    states2.pop(1)
    states2.insert(1, 'TX')
    state_variable = print(input("Enter the abbreviation of another state of your choice: "))
    states2.append(state_variable)
    states2 = states2[::-1]
    returned_states = states2
    print(returned_states)
    return returned_states

main()
```

Whenever I run the program, I only end up getting the first part of the code - as in the states are printed out nice and neat. From there, I have no idea to proceed. I would love some help going in the right direction. Thank you.

**Code edit 1:**

```
    def main():
        states1 = ["AL", "AK", "AZ", "AR", "CA", "CO", "CT", "DE", "FL", "GA"]
        for words in states1:
            print(words, end=" ")
        states2 = states1[3:7]
    def list_func(states2):
        states2.pop(1)
        states2.insert(1, 'TX')
        state_variable = input("Enter the abbreviation of another state of your choice: ")
        states2.append(state_variable)
        states2.reverse(states2)
        returned_states = list_func(states2)
        print(returned_states)
        return states2
def main():
      list_func()
main()
```

**Code edit 2:**

```
def list_func(states2):
    states1 = ["AL", "AK", "AZ", "AR", "CA", "CO", "CT", "DE", "FL", "GA"]
    for words in states1:
        print(words, end=" ")
    states2 = states1[3:7]
    states2.pop(1)
    states2.insert(1, 'TX')
    state_variable = input("Enter the abbreviation of another state of your choice: ")
    states2.append(state_variable)
    states2.reverse(states2)
    returned_states = list_func(states2)
    print(returned_states)
    return states2
list_func(states2)
```

Comment: You have two functions here, main and list_func. You call main (last line of your code) and you never call list_func. That is why list_func is never runs.

Comment: I ended up calling the list_func back to the main, but now I get an error saying that list_func() is missing 1 required positional argument: 'states2' - any idea why?

Comment: [Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32939968/edit) your code in the question to show me what you did

Comment: Note that on [codereview.se] at least, updating the code in the question is *discouraged* because it hides what the answers and comments refer to, making them harder to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, there are some major concepts you need to review, namely how functions work and how to pass parameters to functions. Luckily, in Python there are many online resources for this.

For now, I will explain why your code doesn't work. You have added a second main function (and done some strange indentation). You don't need that new main function because you already had a main function that was working fine.

Here's your original `main` function:

```
def main():
    states1 = ["AL", "AK", "AR", "AZ", "CA", "CO", "CT", "DE", "FL", "GA"]
    for words in states1:
        print(words, end=" ")
    states2 = states1[3:7]
```

Let's go through the steps of your task:

- create a list named states1 that holds the two-letter abbreviations of the first 10 USA states, in alphabetical order. (CHECK)
- use a loop to process the list and display the abbreviations all on the same line, separated by a single space. See sample output. (CHECK)
- make a second list named states2 by slicing. This new list must hold the middle four state abbreviations from states1. (CHECK)
- execute a function named list_func with states2 as its sole argument

Okay, so this is where the issue is. You need to execute `list_func` in `main` sequentially after printing the states. You do that using the following:

```
states2 = list_func(states2)
```

This is because `list_func` takes in an argument (`states2`) so when you call it, you need to pass an argument.

Those are my suggestions for getting over this hump in your task, there will be problems ahead, but try to solve them on your own first and then if you absolutely need to, come to StackOverflow with specific questions about specific parts of your code.

Here's my code suggestion:

```
def main():
    states1 = ["AL", "AK", "AR", "AZ", "CA", "CO", "CT", "DE", "FL", "GA"]
    for words in states1:
        print(words, end=" ")
    states2 = states1[3:7]
    states2 = list_func(states2) 
    # don't forget to print here

def list_func(states2):
    states2.pop(1)
    states2.insert(1, 'TX')
    state_variable = input("Enter the abbreviation of another state of your choice: ")
    states2.append(state_variable)
    states2.reverse(states2)
    returned_states = list_func(states2)
    print(returned_states)
    return states2

main()
```

Comment: So I decided to run the code just for a quick test. It turns out that there's still an error when I run it - It has three different errors when user input is taken into account, saying that reverse() takes no arguments. Not really sure why that would be happening. And what exactly should I be printing? The slice after I take states1?

Comment: @thewhyguy you're right. Like I said in the answer, this solves why `list_func` wasn't running but there are many problems with that function. A simple google search on how to reverse a list will solve your problem. Try to keep stack overflow questions as one issue per question.

Comment: So I ended up figuring my code out and getting it to work. I am, however, having an issue formatting. When I run my program, which I have edited in the original post, I end up with one long string of sentences (AL AK AR AZ CA CO CT DE FL GA Enter the abbreviation of another state of your choice: ) which I want to be separated. I tried putting "\n" in a few places but it didn't end up working out.

Comment: @thewhyguy did you try putting it at the beginning of "Enter the abbreviation..."?

Comment: I ended up putting it at the end of the list after 'GA' and it's fine now. I have but one last question - when I enter the abbreviation and the final result is printed out, it ends up showing up like this - [' NY', 'CT', 'CO', 'TX', 'AZ'] - is there a way to fix it? I can't think of any ways to fix the syntax in this case.

Comment: @thewhyguy if your code for printing is the same as in this answer, then it is printing the list as a list and that's just how lists print. If you read you task list, you can see that you are actually supposed to print the states in the main function, the same way you printed the other ones.

Answer (score 0):

Let me show you how to fix this.

Your `main()` function is (almost) fine. There's just one thing you have to do in it: you must call `list_func` with your `states2` variable.

So:

```
def list_func(states2):
    states2.pop(1)
    states2.insert(1, 'TX')
    state_variable = input("Enter the abbreviation of another state of your choice: ")
    states2.append(state_variable)
    states2 = states2[::-1] # REVERSE A LIST LIKE THIS
    returned_states = states2
    print(returned_states)
    return returned_states

def main():
    states1 = ["AL", "AK", "AR", "AZ", "CA", "CO", "CT", "DE", "FL", "GA"]
    for words in states1:
        print(words, end=" ")
    states2 = states1[3:7]
    list_func(states2) # call list_func with your states2 variable.

main()
```

This should work. Your `list_func` function was broken. This should fix it.

Comment: Are you saying to switch the order of my code? As in put list_func first and then follow it up with main? Trying to make sense of what you're saying to do

Comment: From the instructions: "*then append it to the list reverse the list return the list to main; [..] back in main ...*". He can't really do that without a 'main'.

Comment: No. All I did was get rid of your main function and call list_func. You didn't call list_func in your code, which is why it wasn't behaving as expected.

Comment: I wouldn't call having a main function a bad habit: it helps scope variables that shouldn't be global, and makes it easier to modularize and test the code. (Hmm, I might start doing it.) Anyway, it sounds like it's a requirement of the exercise: "back in main, use a loop to iterate over the returned list".

Comment: Maybe it should be named something more descriptive then, don't you think?

Comment: So I ended up changing it to one function (which is now updated in the main post) but now it says states2 isn't defined in the error message.

Comment: @thewhyguy your assignment clearly wants you to have a function called main. Don't put it in one function!

Comment: Unfortunately, now it's saying states1 isn't defined. As a result, It still is not working.